# POST request says "405 GET not supported" with Spring security enabled

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I enable Spring security using a class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, I receive this error when I send `POST` requests:

```
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
```

I get an error that `GET` is not allowed when I'm sending `POST`... I've been unable to figure this out for hours.

It works perfectly fine if I comment out `@EnableWebSecurity` in my main class and the `WebSecurityConfigrerAdapter` class as shown below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(-20)
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/fonts/**", "/videos/**")
          .permitAll()
        .and()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
          .authorizeRequests()                      
          .antMatchers("/", "/join", "/login", "/about", "/contact", "/index.html")
          .permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()                            
        .and().exceptionHandling()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
        .and()
          .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html").permitAll()
        .and()
          .csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

Here's my Spring controller by the way, if needed:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<BusinessUser> login(@RequestBody BusinessUser inputUser) {
        BusinessUser requestedUser = businessUserService.findByUsername(inputUser.getUsername());
        if(requestedUser != null)
            if(BCrypt.checkpw(inputUser.getPassword(), requestedUser.getPassword()))
                return new ResponseEntity<>(requestedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Again, that controller works fine and is able to receive POST requests as well as return user info in JSON format EXCEPT for when I have the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class (which I need to enable OAuth2.0 and CSRF protection later).

Comment: To what URL are you sending POST request to ?

Comment: @11thdimension http://localhost:8090/login

Comment: @JakeMiller Are you sure `/login` is not prefixed with another route which is defined at the class level? Anyway, of course if you try to access a URL by writing it in the browser's bar, you're going to make a GET request. You need to use AJAX to do a POST...

Comment: one thing i noticed about .formLogin().loginPage: you don't seem to be satisfying all of the requirements according to this documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurer.html#loginPage(java.lang.String) specifically the part about the http params.

Comment: @JohnK That was the issue! Was removing stuff at random to see if it'd fix it and this fixed it.

Comment: @JakeMiller you can probably add that line back in once you satisfy those requirements.

Comment: @JohnK I appreciate the resource. If you wanna post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @JakeMiller I'll add the docs as a top level answer so anyone who stumbles across this a year from now will hopefully see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add a little more documentation for posterity. As Jake said, the line

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
```

Was in fact the problem. According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurer.html#loginPage(java.lang.String)) there are several requirements for loginPage:

- It must be an HTTP POST
- It must be submitted to
  AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.loginProcessingUrl(String)
- It
  should include the username as an HTTP parameter by the name of
  usernameParameter(String)
- It should include the password as an HTTP
  parameter by the name of passwordParameter(String)

The method definition is missing the required http parameters that the loginPage() method requires.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation! I figured out through trial and error what the problem was but had absolutely no idea why that line was causing an error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

This line was causing an error...

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
```

Removed it and now everything is working fine.